# My Mac's password refuses to change

Tags: vpn, password, mac

I work for a large corporation, and I work on a Macbook Pro.  The company has a fancy arrangement where the password I use to connect to the VPN is "synched" to the password I use to log on to my laptop.

My Mac password refuses to "synch" to the VPN password.  I have set it several times by going to Preferences -> Users -> Change Password, but it won't actually change.  If I lock my screen and unlock it, I have to use the original password, not the one I changed it too.

I'm working with an IT guy from my company.  She deleted my keychain file several times.  No dice.

Has anyone else encountered a similar situation?  How did you solve it?  What's going on behind the scenes?

. . . . . . Regards, Rick

Comment: Serverfault is for questions about *managing* servers, not using them; [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com) and [Superuser](https://superuser.com) are better places to ask about things like this. Also, it'd help to describe, as accurately as possible, what the "fancy arrangement" is that syncs the VPN and login passwords.

Answer (score 0):

Gordon Davisson, I believe it is a question about managing the server, not using it.

I was not able to do anything to fix the problem.  The server administrator had to do things to get me connected.

The solution was:  She removed me from being "registered" with the network.  She removed my certificates, for instance, and issued new ones.  She was doing things at blinding speed, and I didn't follow everything, but that was the gist of it.

Perhaps someone will benefit from seeing how the problem was solved in my case.  If you don't feel that leaving this information here is useful, I will delete it.